# Getting text from a Textview and adding it to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

So here's my problem its been bugging me for a while but when I try to get the text from a textview (custom number picker) and add it as an array value,  the array won't let me input the textview value (sonyR).

Custom number picker widget :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String getString = String.valueOf(tvSony.getText());
    int current1 = Integer.parseInt(getString);

    if (v == btnUp1) {
        if (current1 < nEnd) {
            current1++;
            tvSony.setText(String.valueOf(current1));
        }
    }

    if (v == btnDown1) {
        if (current1 > nStart) {
            current1--;
            tvSony.setText(String.valueOf(current1));
        }
    }

        sonyR = current1;
    Log.i("sonyR ouput =", String.valueOf(sonyR));
```

Array, if value has been entered before, find the value and display it. if not make a new array value

```
private void sun32() {
    ArrayList<Integer> sun32A = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (sun32A.contains(sonyR)) {
        sun32A.get(Integer.valueOf(sonyR)); 
        tvSony.setText(sonyR);
    } else {
        tvSony.getText(Integer.valueOf(sonyR));<-----here is the error 
        sun32A.add(sonyR);
    }
    return;
}
```

EDIT : Just to confirm here is an image of the UI layout [image: UI]

Comment: Try: in your "else"- assign sonyR then add it to ArrayList. Currently your'e getting the value, then adding another variable. You're adding a value from another method.

Comment: can you post an example please as I think i've tried this, but it would be great to see what you suggest

Comment: 'int sonyR = tvSony.getText(Integer.valueOf(sonyR); sun32A.add(sonyR);'

Comment: always get the error : getText in TextView cannot be applied to (Java.lang.Integer)

Comment: Oh, you just updated your code example. I thought it could just be an unboxing issue, but now it looks like what @AnnaBillstrom said above. You're not assigning the int correctly. Try her code.

Comment: Wait, tvSony is your TextView? getText() doesn't take any args, so you need to do it like this: int sonyR = Integer.valueOf(tvSony.getText()); sun32A.add(sonyR);

Comment: No luck guys still crashes any other suggestions

Comment: Did you intend to get the return value of `sun32A.get()` and display that in the `tvSony` TextView?  Also, why are you not capturing the return value of `tvSony.getText()` It's hard to figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: basically I'm trying to check for  the value of textView tvSony in an array. If there is a value great show the value in the tetview. if not capture the value entered in the textview to a variable within the array.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the array- it's probably data casting.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer again to fix the other problems. Basically, you need to make sure you are dealing with Strings when setting/getting text from TextView. So make sure ints get converted correctly. And be aware that getText() returns CharrSequence, which is not the same as a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your posted code is that `getText()` shouldn't take any arguments.

Also, `TextView.getText()` returns a `CharSequence`, not a `String`. You should convert it by doing `toString()` before calling `Integer.valueOf()`. Try this code and see if it works:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sun32A = new ArrayList<Integer>(); <---- Variable moved to outside of method.

private void sun32() {

    if (sun32A.contains(sonyR)) {
        // removed irrelevant code line
        tvSony.setText(String.valueOf(sonyR)); <----- Convert the int to String before setting text.

    } else {
        int myInt = Integer.valueOf(tvSony.getText().toString()); <----- fixed code 
        sun32A.add(myInt);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be "sonyR". I just picked that variable name from the original code. I'll change it now. Also, the rest of the code is from the OP question. I just copied and pasted everything except the "fixed code" line. You're right, though. It does nothing. I'll remove that line.

Comment: Yeah, totally.  It's still really unclear what the OP wants to do here.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a misuse of the spinner. There's a callback that gives you position, from that, add/remove from class array.

Comment: sorry it was suppose to say number picker ^

Comment: Wow, this has more problems than I thought. The more I look at it, the more broken it seems. tvSony.setText(sonyR) won't work if sonyR is an int, since setText takes int as a resource id. Yeah, the OP really needs to clarify what they want to do and then rework this entire thing.

Comment: Hopefully  the image  I uploaded conveys it a bit better than I did.

Comment: @Zylo, did you try my updated code? If it doesn't work, what's the error? Also, what's the purpose of your sun32A = new ArrayList<Integer>()? Do you realize that the ArrayList gets reset every time sun32() is called?

Comment: I did not is there a way to stop this from happening ?

Comment: You need to move the variable declaration outside of the method. I'll update the code again to illustrate. Please mark answer as correct if it fixes your problem.